# monthly grouping users who have performed an action

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables..

1)Users
With Columns:

```
              userid      createddate
               1          01/01/2016
               2          02/01/2016
               3          03/01/2016
```

2)Plays
With Columns:

```
             userid       playdate
              1          07/03/2016
              2          06/04/2016
```

Dates shown above are in MM/dd/yyyy format
From table Plays I got a table enrichedplays which has only one top row per userid

The users table has some 5 mil rows and enrichedplays has around 3mil rows.
There are a lot of users who though are in Users are not in Plays.

I need to group monthly Users (on MONTH(createddate)) with userid who are present in plays.

What I mean is in month January there were 10 users in Users table.
Of these 10 users only 5 are present in Plays table and it does not matter for which month they are present.

So, in my resultant data i need 5 against January.

So, for above sample data the result would be

```
Jan-2016   1
Feb-2016   1
March-2016 0
```

Though, I'm using SQL SERVER, it might change and so would appreciate answers which are standard sql.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result from that sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query,

```
SELECT createddate, SUM(CASE WHEN ep.userid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) sum_value
FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN enrichedplays ep
  ON u.userid = ep.userid
GROUP BY createddate;
```

Note: Kindly convert the createddate to your required format.

Comment: I need the number of distinct users per month who have played.. this query I think provides no of plays  for users who joined that month.. will it help if I changed plays here to enrichedplays..

Comment: If `enrichedplays` has **one record per _userid_** then you can use that instead of `plays` table

Answer (score 0):

You need to group users on basis of month and year from `createddate`. 
Check the below query and hope it helps you:

```
declare @users table(userid int, createddate datetime)
declare @plays table(userid int, playdate datetime)

Insert into @users
select 1, '01/01/2016'
union 
select 2, '01/01/2016'
union 
select 1, '02/01/2016'
union 
select 2, '03/01/2016'
union 
select 3, '03/01/2016'



Insert into @plays
select 1, '01/01/2016'
union 
select 2, '01/01/2016'


select format(u.createddate,'MMM-yyyy'), SUM(CASE WHEN p.userid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) sum_value
from @users u
left join @plays p on p.userid = u.userid
Group By format(u.createddate,'MMM-yyyy')
```